# Replacing wordpress footer with custom html one

Tags: php, html, wordpress

i'm new in wordpress and i'd like to replace the footer with a pure html code.
i mean, i till want the "container" generated by wp, but inside i want to use pure html code.
i tried changing the content of `"partials/footer-layout.php"` to this code, and i'm able to see the code, but not to click the links...

any ideas?

```
<?php
/**
 * @package Make
 */

// Footer Options
$footer_layout = (int) get_theme_mod( 'footer-layout', ttfmake_get_default( 'footer-layout' ) );
?>

<footer id="site-footer" class="site-footer footer-layout-<?php echo esc_attr( $footer_layout ); ?>" role="contentinfo">
    <div class="footer-text">
    <!-- CUSTOM FOOTER CODE STARTS HERE --> 
        <div class="footer-custom-container">
        <div class="footer-column-one">
        <h6>Title</h6>
        <ul>
        <a href="#">About us</a>
        <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-column-two">
        <h6>first column</h6>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">User guides</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Download app</a></li>
        </ul></div>
        <div class="footer-column-three">
        <h6>Social & media</h6>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Press</a></li>
        </ul></div>
        <div class="footer-column-four">
        <h6>&nbsp;</h6>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
        </ul></div>
        <div class="footer-column-five">
        <h6>Title</h6>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#">For business</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">For installers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Terms & conditions</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Privacy policy</a></li>
        </ul></div>
        <div class="footer-column-six">
        <h6>first column</h6>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
        </ul></div>
        </div>  

        <!-- CUSTOM FOOTER CODE ENDS HERE -->
</div>

</footer>
```

Comment: There is no link provided in any of the anchor tag. <a href="#">

Comment: You are not providing real links to anchor (`a`) tag.

Comment: yeah ok i know, but shoulden't work anyway adding a # at the bottom of the url?
And anyway, also with real links it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML code isn't XHTML-compliant. There's a missing `<li>...</li>`.

Some possible solutions:
1- try to add links to the anchor tags and check if it works.
2- check if there's a HTML element which overlaps the anchor tags. Use firebug or any other developer tool to check if there's an overlapping element.
3- check if there's a Javascript event which is called once you click on the anchor. Use a Javascript debugger (Firebug etc.).

Here's the updated code:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package Make
 */

// Footer Options
$footer_layout = (int) get_theme_mod( 'footer-layout', ttfmake_get_default( 'footer-layout' ) );
?>

<footer id="site-footer" class="site-footer footer-layout-<?php echo esc_attr( $footer_layout ); ?>" role="contentinfo">
    <div class="footer-text">
    <!-- CUSTOM FOOTER CODE STARTS HERE --> 
        <div class="footer-custom-container">
            <div class="footer-column-one">
                <h6>Title</h6>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-column-two">
                <h6>first column</h6>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">User guides</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Download app</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-column-three">
                <h6>Social & media</h6>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Press</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-column-four">
                <h6>&nbsp;</h6>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-column-five">
                <h6>Title</h6>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">For business</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">For installers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Terms & conditions</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Privacy policy</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-column-six">
                <h6>first column</h6>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <!-- CUSTOM FOOTER CODE ENDS HERE -->
    </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Often when you can't click a link, it is a case that a layer is positioned on top of it.

Use a code inspector such as Firebug, and see if there are any 'invisible layers' above that area.

There is also the chance that css has `cursor:none` applied so it doesn't look like you can click it, but it can.  Try replacing your # links with real links.

Also, `<a href="#">About us</a>` needs `li` tags around it, but I doubt that is the issue.